# How to convert linked tables to local tables in access using VBA or vbscript

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, vba

I am using vbscript in excel so far but trying to involve access too. I have a DB in Access with 3 linked tables from excel sheets. So far i manage to open Access and refresh the data in the tables. Now because sheets contains many data Access is getting slow.
Is there any vbscript way after i update the linked tables to convert them to local?

If not passible, does anyone knows if I can make a macro in access to do that and run it when opening file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SELECT INTO ... IN ExternalDatabase` via ADO as described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/295646/en-us). (Just reverse the direction of the transfer)